# If sigwait() blocks, when is the accepted signal actually "selected"?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, posix, rtos

There are two real-time threads. The first one has low priority and it is waiting for all possible signals in `sigwait()` (so all signals are blocked and `sigmask` passed to the function has all signals enabled). The second one has high priority and sends two signals to the first (low priority) thread - it first sends `SIGRTMAX` and then `SIGRTMIN`.

POSIX spec for `sigwait()` ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwait.html ) says this:

> If no signal in set is pending at the time of the call, the thread shall be suspended until one or more becomes pending.
>
> [...]
>
> Should any of the multiple pending signals in the range SIGRTMIN to SIGRTMAX be selected, it shall be the lowest numbered one.

The sequence of events in a real-time operating system would look like that:

```
(H)...............signal(SIGRTMAX)===signal(SIGRTMIN)===...
(L)===sigwait().........................................===
      ^           ^                  ^                  ^
      1           2                  3                  4
```

- `(H)` - high priority thread
- `(L)` - low priority thread
- `.` - thread is not running
- `=` - thread is running

The 4 interesting points:

1. low priority thread blocks on `sigwait()`, no signals are currently pending, all signals are blocked, high priority thread is not yet started;
2. high priority thread starts and sends `SIGRTMAX` signal to low priority thread, which is unblocked, but not allowed to run, as high priority thread is still running;
3. high priority thread continues running and sends `SIGRTMIN` signal to low priority thread, but low priority thread is still waiting to actually run;
4. high priority thread terminates, low priority thread is allowed to run and return from `sigwait()` call;

Now the problem is that if both `SIGRTMIN` and `SIGRTMAX` signals are pending at the same time, `SIGRTMIN` should be "selected" first. However I'm not sure at which point the signal is actually "selected" - is it selected by the kernel at "2" or maybe it is selected by code in `sigwait()` executed in low priority thread, so at "4"? That's why I'm not sure whether in the scenario above, the `sigwait()` call would actually select `SIGRTMIN` or `SIGRTMAX`. Maybe such details are "implementation defined"?

The questions is releated to the real-time operating system for microcontrollers I'm developing ( https://github.com/DISTORTEC/distortos ). Currently my code "selects" the signal during generation, so at "2" (my code would return `SIGRTMAX` first), but I'm no longer sure that's the correct way to do it...

Comment: Shouldn't this "*3. high priority thread starts  ....*" read "*3. high priority thread continues running ...*"? Otherwise this could imply the HP thread stopped running. And if it did, then things were clear.

Comment: @alk - good catch (; sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider the scenario described a race. So, well, the outcome is implementation defined.

Signals should not be used for synchronisation. If the order of receiving the two  signals is important (to the application) it should take the appropriate actions to synchronise (them).

Comment: Do you have an opinion about which of the two options described in the question is more appropriate/expected/...? (;

Comment: No, as I don't know anything about the/your implementation. In general I'd try to code this in way that reduces buffering to a minimum, so that `sigwait()`'s implemenation has the best chances to get the most up-to-date content of the signal list, when it comes to pulling a signal from the list.@FreddieChopin

Comment: On the other hand one could argue the relevant point in time is when `sigwait()` got called, so the implementation might just go the other wait wrong and grap the ealierst arriving signal. @FreddieChopin As I said "its implementation defined" and as you are the implementer, just do as you like ... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your input! As I wrote in the question, previously I'd "select" the signal in point 2, but now I changed that to point 4 - this somehow feels a bit better...

Comment: Correction: "*... go the other wait wrong ...*" should read: "*... go the other way round ...*" ... :-}} @FreddieChopin